# A problem with angular speed and speed of an oscillation question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, angular-velocity

[image]

Hello,
So in this question the first thing I did was to find the speed of both the blocks just after the spring is uncompressed by using conservation of energy. ( v = 0.5m/s).

And in part (b) I wanted to use Newton's second law when the block1 reaches Xm = 0.2m. The only force acting to the block is the spring which is k.x = 100N/m x 0.2m. = 20N so a = 20N/9kg. 
Now to find angular speed, w = √(a/Xm)= 10/3 rad/s. Now the problem is that, v = w.Xm but my w and v results do not satisfy this. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not altogether clear from your description what calculation you are making.

The force from the spring at maximum compression decreases as the spring extends and pushes the two blocks to the right. This force is not constant so it is not easy to apply $F=ma$. You would need to integrate the force over distance or time to find the work done (=change in KE) or the impulse applied (=change in momentum). It is much easier to use the conservation of energy.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I did not understand the question well, arent the two blocks moving together until they pass the equilibrium point? And I thought that the maximum acceleration would be when the spring is pulled to Xm where the instantaneous force is k.Xm, am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I think I have misunderstood your calculation. ... You have used a mass of $m_1=9kg$ but the force has to accelerate *both* blocks ($m_1+m_2$).